# How to stop ROS script that starts after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, ros

I've created a script that would check whether a certain server is running and restart it in event of crash (the script runs endlessly every 10 seconds).

**How can I stop/ignore/break the script?** I cannot run any commands and CTRL+C, CTRL+A, CTRL+Z do NOT work.

The main problem is also that the machine server is not running so the IP is not reachable with MobaXterm. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox with only Terminal, no GUI!

The RestartScript:

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
        COUNT="$(pgrep -f Odie | wc -l)"
        echo $'\n'
        echo "Number of Odie processes (COUNT) = $((COUNT))"
        echo "$(pgrep -fla Odie)"

        case "$(screen -ls | grep Odie | wc -l)" in
        0) echo "Restarting Odie:       $(date)" | sudo tee -a /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        bash -c "exec -a OnlyOdie ./screen_start.sh"
        ;;
        1) # all ok
        echo "Process is running:       $(date)" | sudo tee -a  /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        ;;
        2) echo "Removed double Odie:   $(date)"  | sudo tee -a /var/log/OdieLog.txt
        #kill $(pgrep -f OnlyOdie | awk '{print $1}')
        screen -ls | awk -vFS='\t|[.]' '/Odie/ {system("screen -S "$2" -X quit")}'
        ;;
        esac
sleep 10
done
```

screen_start.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
SCREEN_COUNT="$(screen -ls | grep Odie | wc -l)"

if [ "$SCREEN_COUNT" -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "SCREEN_COUNT = ZERO"
        screen -sdm ./start.sh -S Odie
fi
```

Sadly I can not add the ROS file content since I cannot access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to access it from other sources I found a way to switch between screens in Linux using: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (goes to <kbd>F6</kbd>).

This made it possible to log in as a user and re-edit the file / terminate the process.